Set entity position with an anchor entity after DragGesture
I'm a bit stuck on placing an anchor entity within an immersive space on another wall with drag gestures.
What I want:

User enters an ImmersiveSpace
A photo frame appears before them sticks to the wall
User can then move the frame entity to another vertical wall using DragGesture().

The issue I'm having is not able to move the frame entity to another vertical wall with drag gesture. I want to move the entity on the same wall and move to the other vertical wall and restrict to place on the corners.
Here's my code so far.
@State private var anchor = AnchorEntity()
var body: some View {
        RealityView{ content in                        
            let wallAnchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical, classification: .wall, minimumBounds: SIMD2<Float>(0.1, 0.1)), trackingMode: .once)
            let material = UnlitMaterial(color: .clear)
            let planeEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1), materials: [material])
            
            planeEntity.name = "plane"
            async let textEntity = ModelEntity(named: “Photo”)
    
            if let textEntity = try? await textEntity {
               planeEntity.addChild(textEntity)
                appleWatch = textEntity
                wallAnchor.addChild(planeEntity)
                anchor = wallAnchor
            }
            
            wallAnchor.components.set(InputTargetComponent(allowedInputTypes:.indirect))
            wallAnchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true) 
            content.add(wallAnchor)
        }    .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            let startPosition = startPosition ?? anchor.position
                            self.startPosition = startPosition
                      
                            let delta = SIMD3<Float>(
                                Float(value.translation.width) / 1000.0, 
                                0,
                                Float(value.translation.height) / 1000.0 
                            )
                            anchor.position = startPosition + delta
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            startPosition = nil
                        }
                )



Repeatable Raycast Query
To jump onto a perpendicular wall or surface, you definitely need a Tracked Raycasting algorithm, which isn't currently available in ARKit/RealityKit for visionOS 1.2. Tracked raycasting considerably improves hit-testing techniques by repeating the query for an anchor's position in succession. However, this is achieved at the expense of a "heavy-metal" processing. The final code snippet in this post will show you how to implement a tracked raycaster in ARKit/RealityKit/SceneKit for iOS app.

You can test how ARTrackedRaycast works in iOS.
